# How to implement Marker Clustering for Google Maps in Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I have implemented Google Maps successfully in my App. I have to implement Marker Clustering for **Xamarin Android.**

The [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering) here gives a good explanation regarding how to implement but i am not able to understand how to refer the package.

I got few source files but it is not helping as i am not aware how to refer the jar files. The documents i got is related to Java but not C#. Here are the few links:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13569/google-maps-android-api-utility-library-support/p2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `Xamarin.Android` Binding project that includes the `android-maps-utils.aar` file.

Note: I have [forked](https://github.com/sushihangover/XamarinGoogleMapClustering) an older Github repo that included a binding project and example and updated it to the latest version of `android-maps-utils.aar` (`v0.4.3` as of this post).

Just clone that repo and copy the entire `GoogleMapsUtility` project into your `Xamarin.Android` solution and add that to your solution (via Add Existing Project).

Then you can create a Google Map like you would normally, i.e.:

```
GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
    .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
    .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(true)
    .InvokeMapToolbarEnabled(true)
    .InvokeZoomGesturesEnabled(true)
    .InvokeRotateGesturesEnabled(true)
    .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);
```

Then you can add your Map markers to the `ClusterManager` and let it manage the clustering:

```
_clusterManager = new ClusterManager(this, _map);
_clusterManager.SetOnClusterClickListener(this);
_clusterManager.SetOnClusterItemClickListener(this);
_map.SetOnCameraChangeListener(_clusterManager);
_map.SetOnMarkerClickListener(_clusterManager);
```

I modified the original example to create 20 markers in a log. spiral pattern to test the cluster at various zoom levels:

```
private void AddClusterItems()
{
    double lat = 47.59978;
    double lng = -122.3346;

    var items = new List<ClusterItem>();

    // Create a log. spiral of markers to test clustering
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        var t = i * Math.PI * 0.33f;
        var r = 0.005 * Math.Exp(0.1 * t);
        var x = r * Math.Cos(t);
        var y = r * Math.Sin(t);
        var item = new ClusterItem(lat + x, lng + y);
        items.Add(item);
    }
    _clusterManager.AddItems(items);
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really cool..I am able to achieve the functionality. May be my question is silly. I am not sure what the .aar file does. Thanks a lot!. This thread will be helpful for any beginners like me. Thanks again for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Note: it shows '_mapFragment.Map' is obsolete: 'deprecated'. Will it be an issue in future.. as of now it is working perfectly.

Comment: @Dilip The 'aar' bundle is the binary distribution of an Android Library Project. So this `.aar` file contains the actual Java classes and resources from Google (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils). The `Xamarin.Android` binding project provides a "C# wrapper" around that Java code to allow it to function in the `Xamarin.Android`/C#/.Net world

Comment: @Dilip Yes, `MapFragment.Map` has been superseded by `MapFragment.GetMapAsync`. Not a huge change in the code, when I get a chance I'll update it to the new async style and let you know...

Comment: thanks!!. I have changed it to 'MapFragment.GetMapAsync' in my code and it is working fine...

Comment: @Dilip Glad to hear it, I updated the source in my repo to GetMapAsync anyway in case someone needs it also.

Comment: Thanks for this - migrating from Android Studio to VS Xamarin and got this up and running very quickly with your project

Comment: is there a solution for xamarin iOS? is there a bidning for google map iOS utility library?

Comment: @Receme I created one back in July when it was released. There are a number of them one github... Here is one, (Note: I personally have not used it) : https://github.com/NateRickard/Google-Maps-Utils-Binding

Comment: Note that `OnCameraChangeListener` should be now changed to `OnCameraIdleListener` according to [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering).

Comment: How to directly use the nuget package Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils?
I can't find a way to include that in my project.

Comment: @frankie That package is not the one I published, you might want to ask the author of that binding: https://github.com/alexsorokoletov/Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils

Comment: Is it possible to get the same functionality using xamarin.forms for ios? @SushiHangover

Comment: @KalleP Yes, Google has a clustering utility for iOS https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils / https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering Just create a binding for it and Apple has clustering builtin to the their iOS map via MapKit / MKClusterAnnotation / https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkclusterannotation?language=objc

Comment: Ok, so no one has written code for it already? @SushiHangover

Comment: @KalleP I have but do not know if anyone has published one, I'd search search GitHub first....