# How to Cluster Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps Pin in PCL Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Since I am doing a map based cross-platform project on Xamarin, And I'm stuck to the point where I need to cluster markers when zooming out. 
**things I had tried:**

- GoogleMapUtility Project.
- And tried to use ClusterManager of GoogleMapUtility through dependency. so that I can add a pin to cluster manager From PCL project. But to initialize cluster manager I need a Native Map instance i.e. Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap.(don't know how to get)

I know I can achieve it with that with custom map renderer, but I cant do that coz. a lot of code related to map is already written, I don't want to rewrite a Code. So Is there any possibility that I can get a native instance of the map that I can use on dependency service.

I created CustomRenderer For Map without creating a customMap class at PCL (inherit Map class) the code is below. but it's not get triggered. What wrong I am doing here...

custom renderer code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Map), typeof(MarkerClusterRenderer))]
namespace SamplingApp.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class MarkerClusterRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        ClusterManager _clusterManager;
        protected override void OnMarkerCreated(Pin outerItem, Marker innerItem)
        {
            base.OnMarkerCreated(outerItem, innerItem);
            AddToMarkerCluster();
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

    public void AddToMarkerCluster()
    {
        _clusterManager = new ClusterManager(Android.App.Application.Context, NativeMap);
        //[do other things here]
    }

}
}
```

since I am is new to xamarin. little guidance is appreciated.
am I in the right direction?

Thank you in advance. and sorry for my English.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323777/how-to-implement-marker-clustering-for-google-maps-in-xamarin

Comment: thank you, but I already gone through that link. i had included GoogleMapUtility Project. since iam using PCL Project so i have created custom renderer to use clusterManager as above. but the problem is Renderer is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

> I created CustomRenderer For Map without creating a customMap class at PCL (inherit Map class) the code is below. but it's not get triggered. What wrong I am doing here...

If you want to customize the map, you need to create a custom class for map control in PCL:

```
public class CustomMap:Map
{

}
```

And use it in xaml:

```
<local:CustomMap WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="200"
        x:Name="MyMap"
        IsShowingUser="true"
        MapType="Hybrid"/>
```

And renderer:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(SamplingApp.CustomMap),
  typeof(MarkerClusterRenderer))]
namespace SamplingApp.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class MarkerClusterRenderer:MapRenderer
    {
        ...
```

Then, your renderer's codes will be triggered correctly.

Comment: You mean, i cannot make a renderer for all instance of Map. like we do for Entry or Button? button renderer eg:

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(RoundedButtonRendererAndroid))]
namespace SamplingApp.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class RoundedButtonRendererAndroid:ButtonRenderer
    {}
}

tq anyway. :)

Comment: I have also tried with the original `Map` class, but it just doesn't work. I don't know why, might caused by some internal codes of the framework.  With a custom map, you can still use all the functionality of the original class.